# How to add conditional Gemspec dependencies

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have made a Gem that optionally logs with Sentry or Airbrake, depending on the ENV variables. I have these in my Gemspec but I only need one or the other:

```
spec.add_runtime_dependency "sentry-raven"
spec.add_runtime_dependency "airbrake"
```

Is there a way to only include the one that the end user needs, based on ENV variables?

Answer (score 1):

You may be best off leaving off both dependencies and adding to your README that a user needs to add the dependency to their own `Gemfile`. I've seen some gems check to see what is defined, raising an error if they don't find anything, as well as allowing the user to configure in their application which tool to use.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible for the simple reason that the Gemspec is executed on *your* computer, not the user's computer. It is executed to *build* the Gem, not install it.

RubyGems does not have a sophisticated dependency system like e.g. `dpkg`/APT has: a Gem either depends on another Gem or it doesn't.